# Is $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ an $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, euclidean-geometry, sobolev-spaces, besov-space

Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^n_+=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times (0,\infty)$ is trivially $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-locally uniform, for $\varepsilon=1$ and any $\delta$ and the arc chosen as the segment of a straight line connecting $x$ and $y$?

The definition:

> A domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-locally uniform for $\varepsilon, \delta>0$ if any $x,y \in \Omega$ with $\| x-y \| \leq \delta$ can be joined by a rectifiable arc $\gamma \subset \Omega$ satisfying for any point $z \in \gamma$
>
> 1. $l(\gamma) \leq \varepsilon \| x-y \|$, and
> 2. $\min\{l(\gamma'), l(\gamma'')\} \leq \mathrm{dist}(z, \partial \Omega)$,
>
> where $l(\gamma)$ is the Euclidean length of the arc $\gamma$, and $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ are the two components of $\gamma\setminus \{z\}$. $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$.

I am only concerned about defining $\partial \Omega$ for an unbounded space.

P.S. if this holds, $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is uniform as well (drop the "locally"), ie $\delta=\infty$; the same should hold for any convex set.

Comment: if $||x-y|| = \delta$ and $\epsilon  = 1$, wont this force the arc to be a straight line ? what is $r$ ?

Comment: The r in your definition should be delta, probably.

Comment: cheers, fixed typo in definition. Yes, it would force the arc to be a straight line -- which should be fine.

Comment: We can pretend $\Omega'$ = Ball of size $\delta$ is your domain and prove this and say $d(z,\partial \Omega') \leq d(z,\partial \Omega)$. Even if its unbounded, inequality should hold. This will solve unboundedness though Ball of size $\delta$ should be contained in $\Omega$ in general. Should be OK in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $\mathbb{R}_+^n = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times (0,\infty)$ is a uniform domain. But no, you cannot take a straight line segment. Take $\mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty)$ and the two points $x=(a,0)$, $y=(a,2)$ with $a > 0$. Then for $z = (a,1)$ we would have $\operatorname{min}\{l(\gamma'), l(\gamma'')\} = 1$ for all $a>0$, but $\lim_{a \to 0} \operatorname{dist}(z, \partial\Omega) = 0$.

Here is a sketch of a proof that $\mathbb{R}_+^n = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times (0,\infty)$ is indeed a uniform domain. Take $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$, construct a square with the line segment between $x$ and $y$ being the diagonal of the square as well as $x$ and $y$ being two of its edges. Let $z \neq x,y$ be the edge of the square that has the greatest $z_n > 0$ value. Connect $x$ and $y$ with two straight line segments via $z$ and the desired conditions are fulfilled.